# Rails: Create a statically served page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, static, asset-pipeline

I purchased a template which I want to use as the landing page of an existing application I have built.

The template has the following format:

```
  |- template
    |- index.html
    |- images
    |- js
    |- css
```

I would like to insert this folder, as it is, into my project and access it like so:

```
  def landing
    render "/app/views/template/index"
  end
```

Currently this approach is not working for me due to the rails pipeline.

Is there any way to overwrite the pipeline and serve this template in a **static** manner?

An alternative approach which I have toyed with is hosting a separate static site (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/static-sites-ruby) and give it my applications current domain name and then linking it to main application.

However, some research has suggested changing the DNS may take a number of days to take effect, which is not an option.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to integrate the JS, CSS, and images with the asset pipeline (that is move them to the appropriate folders in `app/assets/`. The difficulty with that would be that you have to manually change the reference to these things in the index.html file (easier with JS and CSS, might be a little more tedious with images). Then you just create the appropriate route and controller like so:

routes.rb

```
root 'template#index'
```

template_controller.rb

```
def index
end
```

and everything should work (also you may have to change `index.html` to `index.html.erb`).

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could use the **public folder** for this purpose after wrapping the asset links in:

`<%= asset_url('LINK') =>`